# Timeout not happening - Simple Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a piece of code that will show up a message when nothing is entered into a text field, and then disappear (I may make it fade instead of simply disappear but lets walk before we can run...).

What I've done so far looks as so:

```
<div id="msg"></div>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("msg");
    x.innerHTML = "Enter a video URL";
    setTimeout(function() {
        x.innerHTML = "");
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

it seems the timeout function isn't working as when I replace:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    x.innerHTML = "");
}, 1000);
```

with

```
setTimeout(function() {
    x.innerHTML = "A");
}, 1000);
```

The A instantly shows up, signifying the "enter a video" string isn't being executed and the browser is jumping straight to the string I want to be halted.

Comment: could you please reproduce it in a fiddle or so..

Comment: typo `x.innerHTML = "")` should be `x.innerHTML = ""`

Comment: Since you have syntax errors in all your examples, none of them will actually work. If you fix the syntax error, it will work: https://jsfiddle.net/ae83cvc4/ .

Comment: is this actual `x.innerHTML = "")` or you have added `)` by mistake in this question?

Comment: oh god I did mistakenly add a bracket; thanks, though I feel like a lot of time was wasted over a small mistake - im new to javascript - .

Comment: [Learn how to debug JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

You have a miss matched brackets in your timeout:

```
<div id="msg">start</div>
```

JS:

```
var x =  document.getElementById("msg");
x.innerHTML = "Enter a video URL";
setTimeout(function() {
          x.innerHTML = "end";
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this should do it. You had a couple errors..

```
setTimeout(function() {
    x.innerHTML = "A";
}, 1000);
```

edit: didn't notice it wasn't jQuery, so changed my response...

Comment: DOM elements don't have a `html` method.

Comment: Doesn't work, the message now just stays on screen signifying the setTimeout function has had no effect on the text inside the div

Comment: apologies, drilled into my head for me to use jQuery

Comment: updated to remove the error he had, but still using his code... the was too many closing brackets in there before, would have caused error.

Answer (score 0):

The signature is `setTimeout(func,delay)`

So you simply need to fix your typo in the function like :

```
setTimeout(function() {
    x.innerHTML = "SOME_VALUE";
}, 1000);
```